# mq_open() returns "Too many open files" even after increasing limits

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, message-queue

I am trying to establish communication between threads using `POSIX message queues`. I am stuck at a place where `mq_open()` is failing with error `Too many open files`. I tried changing `/etc/sysctl.conf` to set very high limits as:

```
fs.mqueue.msg_max = 60000
fs.mqueue.queues_max = 1000000
```

Also, before running the executable, I am running `ulimit -n 300000` to ensure no errors(earlier value was 1024).

I can't figure out why after these limits, error still persists.

I tried setting high limits as explained above. I have set `queues_max , msg_max` and `ulimit` to higher values. My expectation was that `mq_open` successfully opens the queue but it fails.